# Working with databases in Python without an ORM

Tags: python, database

What is the standard/recommended way to work with a database (MySQL, mostly) in Python?

I don't want an ORM, and the lighter the better. I don't mind writing my own SELECTs but I'd like something that maps a dictionary, for example, to do INSERTs and UPDATEs. I'm mostly a PHP programmer and I'm used to do something like this:

```
$data = array(
  'foo' => 'bar'
);

$insert = $db->insert('table', $data);
```

Is there anything like this for Python? I looked into SQLAlchemy, which apparently everybody uses, and its "SQL Expression" seems nice, but it seems like overkill to use the whole thing to basically write raw SQL.

Comment: First.  Search Stack Overflow.  Many, many question have been asked on MySQL and Python.  Please read up on MySQL-Python (http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/) and the Python DB API (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/).  After reading the resources, please **update** your question with something specific.

Answer (score 5):

To use a dict for inserts, you are looking for a DB driver that supports the ["named" (placeholder) paramstyle](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) (in the link, search for "paramstyle"):

From the [sqlite3 docs](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3):

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect("mydb")    
cur = con.cursor()

who = "Yeltsin"
age = 72

cur.execute("select name_last, age from people where name_last=:who and age=:age",
    {"who": who, "age": age})
print cur.fetchone()
```

Unfortunately for MySQL, the two main drivers, [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) and [oursql](http://packages.python.org/oursql/) do not support the "named" paramstyle. MySQLdb uses the "format" paramstyle (using '%s') and oursql uses the "qmark" paramstyle (using '?'). Both these paramstyles require you to supply a `list` rather than a `dict` of args:

```
x={'bar':1.0,'baz':2.0}
sql='INSERT INTO foo (bar,baz) VALUES (?,?)'
cur.execute(sql,[x['bar'],x['baz']])
```

By the way, if you need a driver to connect with MySQL, use [oursql](http://packages.python.org/oursql/). 
MySQLdb has historically been the go-to driver for Python-MySQL interaction, but that driver uses **regex** to manipulate your SQL and arguments into one quoted string which is then sent to MySQL. In contrast, oursql uses prepared statements, sends the SQL and the arguments separately, [eschewing the need for escaping data](http://packages.python.org/oursql/tutorial.html#parameterization). The oursql way is the right way, and avoids [certain bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879606/including-db-function-calls-in-python-mysqldb-executemany/4880198#4880198) that plagues MySQLdb.

Comment: Nice, I had no idea that there is finally an alternative to MySQLdb. It has become more of a hassle with each new Python version.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need a specific module for the Database system you're working with. SQLite is in the standard library. For mySQL, try [mySQLdb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/). There's a [tutorial here](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/pydbapi.html).